# SQL statement to retrieve data from multiple tables in a database

Tags: sql

I am trying my best to explain the issue. We do have 5 tables M1,M2,M3,M4,M5 and after all we have only one common field M_ID in all the tables. Also M_ID will have different values. So my requirement is to retrieve the records that related to individual M_ID at a time.

Example: If I have M_ID values as 1,2,3,4 etc then for each SQL select I need to retrieve the records for only one M_ID value.

```
M1 Table: M_ID,F1,F2
M2 Table: M_ID,F3,F4
M3 Table: M_ID,F5,F6
```

F* are the fields that can be repetitive multiple times. So I need to take care of Data redundancy too. Each table contains more than 10 fields so can I use Select *?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT M1.F1,M1.F2
       M2.F3,M2.F4,
       M3.F5,M3.F6
FROM M1 INNER JOIN M2 ON M1.M_ID = M2.M_ID
        INNER JOIN M3 ON M1.M_ID=M3.M_ID
WHERE M1.M_ID = @ID_PARAM
```

and so on..(i have done this only for 3 tables from your questions)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response...Can I able to retrieve the records that are related to only one individual M_ID?

Comment: YES..see my updated answer. just pass the id value for which you want to retirive records in place of `@ID_PARAM` in above query

Comment: M_ID value should be dynamic...I am placing this query in a interface and it will be automated...